# Using mhchem in align environment

Tags: mhchem

The list of chemical reactions are written using align environment

```
    \begin{align}
                \ce{
                Ca(OH)_{2} + 2 HCl &\rightarrow CaCl$_2$ + 2 H_{2}O \nonumber \\ 
                Ca(OH)_{2} + HCl &\rightarrow CaOHCl + H_{2}O \nonumber \\
                Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2} &\rightarrow 2 CaOHCl \nonumber 
                   }
                \end{align}
```

It compiles without any problems but for the third reaction on the product side, '2' appears somewhat as subscript but the same does not happen with the `2' of the first reaction on the reactant side. How can we resolve this problem and why does this happen?

The same thing happens when I write

```
    \begin{equation}
            \ce{
                Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2}.2H_{2}O \rightarrow 2CaOHCl.2H_{2}O \nonumber 
            }
            \end{equation}
```

'2' on the product side (of CaOHCl) appears as subscript but not '2' of HCl. Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: `mhchem`  comes with its own version of an arroe pointing from left to right: `->` as in `\ce{Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2}.2H_{2}O -> 2 CaOHCl.2H_{2}O}`. If you, for whatever reason, have to use `\rightarrow`, go for `\rightarrow{}`.

Comment: `Ca(OH)_{2}` could be written as `Ca(OH)2`. `H_{2}O` could be `H2O`. I recommend the documentation at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`mhchem` comes with its own set of reaction arrows that you can access via the following shortcuts:

[image]

Therefore, simply replace `\rightarrow` with `->`. If you want to stick to the shorter `\rightarrow`, you can use `\rightarrow{}` in order to make sure a number following the arrow is not shown as a subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\ce{Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2} & \rightarrow 2 CaOHCl} \\
\ce{Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2} & \rightarrow{} 2 CaOHCl} \\
\ce{Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2} & -> 2 CaOHCl}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \ce{
    Ca(OH)_{2} + 2 HCl &-> CaCl$_2$ + 2 H_{2}O  \\ 
    Ca(OH)_{2} + HCl &-> CaOHCl + H_{2}O  \\
    Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2} & -> 2 CaOHCl  
       }
\end{align*}

\ce{Ca(OH)_{2} + CaCl_{2}.2H_{2}O -> 2 CaOHCl.2H_{2}O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to write `H2O` instead of `H_{2}O`, etc. Also, `\rightarrow` should be `$\rightarrow$`, see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf